# R language split data frame into relevant format for graph

Tags: r, graph

I have a data set with 12,000 rows of the following (IP addresses changed, obviously):

```
Date                        good?   ip
11670 2016-10-31 00:03:30   TRUE  127.0.0.1
11671 2016-10-31 00:03:23   TRUE  127.0.0.1
11672 2016-10-31 00:03:20   TRUE  127.0.0.1
11673 2016-10-31 00:03:11   TRUE  127.0.0.1
11674 2016-10-31 00:03:08   TRUE  127.0.0.1
11675 2016-10-31 00:02:59  FALSE  127.0.0.1
11676 2016-10-31 00:02:53   TRUE  127.0.0.1
11677 2016-10-31 00:02:49  FALSE  127.0.0.1
11678 2016-10-31 00:02:44  FALSE  127.0.0.1
11679 2016-10-31 00:02:40   TRUE  127.0.0.1
```

So, I've done some things to this, like "Get all ip addresses that have over 100 rows of combined TRUE and FALSE", etc.

I'm trying to take the above and transform it into an easily plowable format where I can sort the "good" bool by count and group it into intervals of 1 hour. Something like:

```
date                TRUE  FALSE
2016-10-31 00:00:00 342  1010
2016-10-31 01:00:00 544   890
```

I tried `cut.POSIXt(data$date, breaks = "hour")`, but that didn't preserve the bool state and also gave me an unplottable object.

I tried `lapply(split(votes, cut(votes$date, "hour")), function(x) summary (x[2]))`, which I found online and just happened to fit my use case, but

1) I don't understand a lot of what is happening beyond cut and split
2) It gives me a list with a date in characters followed by a blob of characters, which I can't plot

What transforms and steps should I be taking here? I tried aggregate, but I always lose TRUE/FALSE distinctions.

The goal is to make a plot that has two colored bars per hour interval, blue for total true and red for total false registered in that hour interval.

Comment: Please give a working example, so we can test it. you can use dput()

Comment: @timat I would love to, but I can't because I'm actually using sensitive production data and can't replicate that.

I got the answer though. I very much appreciate your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
```

change the format corresponding to your date format, in your example, it looks like there is an id before the data, you should delete it before.

```
dt$date<- as.POSIXct(dt$date,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",  tz = "GMT")
```

Use cut to generate the hour category

```
dt$break_hour <- cut(dt$date, breaks="hour")
```

Use data.table (faster than R fuinction base like `aggregate`) to create your column

```
dt <- dt[,list(good = sum(good), bad = sum(!good)), by=break_hour ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using `dplyr` based on your example data, assuming `df$Date` is a of type `POSIXct`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(date = format(Date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
           hour = format(Date, "%H"),
           good = as.character(good)) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  spread(key = good, value = count)
#        date  hour `FALSE` `TRUE`
#*      <chr> <chr>   <int>  <int>
#1 2016-10-31    00       3      7
```

If your intention is to plot, you probably don't need the last step of `spread()`, and can use what comes before to plug it into `ggplot2` for example.

Comment: df %>% 
What is this %>% symbol?

Comment: @JapanRob They call it pipe operator, look here http://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/dplyr_tutorial.html

Comment: @timat Thank you!